# Deploy App Engine go app using Cloud Build

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

**Goal:**

Using Cloud Build configuration - build an app into an artifact that can be deployed to app engine.

**Solution that's not working:**

This is `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ['get']
  env: ['PROJECT_ROOT=project-name']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ['build', '.']
  env: ['PROJECT_ROOT=project-name']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
timeout: '1600s'

artifacts:
  objects:
    location: 'gs://project-artifacts/'
    paths: ['project-name']
```

App Engine config `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

And finally `main.go`: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/appengine/helloworld/hello.go

I do understand that the deploy step is now very naive and doesn't even need the previous 2 steps. Consulting the `cloud app` help, I wasn't able to see whether the `deploy` step can accept external artifact.

The deploy step fails with:

```
failed analyzing /workspace: cannot find package "google.golang.org/appengine" in any of:
    ($GOROOT not set)
    /builder/home/go/src/google.golang.org/appengine (from $GOPATH)
GOPATH: /builder/home/go
```

**I'm looking for 2 solutions:**

1. Ideally being able to build artifacts into `project-artifacts` bucket and deploy them using the deploy step
2. If that's not possible I at least need to know how to run `gcloud components install app-engine-go` within the deploy container so it doesn't fail with missing dependency.

Comment: Mmmm..... Interesting question. I've not tried using Cloud Build with App Engine but you've compelled me to try it. From experience, I've found `cloud-builders/go` difficult to configure. I'll have a go and report back!

Comment: Here's an example that uses Cloud Build to deploy an App Engine sample app (https://gist.github.com/DazWilkin/05984055d6e80cfcab6258b3da85e30a). As mentioned, I find the Go build challenging but, this simply mirrors my local `go` structure on the Cloud Build container and then does the deploy from the src directory.

Comment: IIUC to upload directories using `artifacts` you'd either need to add a zip step and upload the zip or enumerate all the files. Alternatively, you may wish to drop `artifacts` and add a `gsutil` build step to recursively copy your artifacts.

Comment: The gist you shared helped me to make the deployment work. But I run the deployment from my project folder that is already deep in the go `src` folder. That means that all my sources are in `/workspace` in the container. I hacked it temporarily by moving my sources to `./app` subfolder. Thanks so much for spending time trying this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a GOPATH outside of your build directory (`/workspace`). For example, `/gopath`.

Additionally, because by default only `/workspace` is preserved between Cloud Build steps, you must put your GOPATH in a volume.

The following complete example works for me:

```
steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ['get', '-d', './...']
  env: ['GOPATH=/gopath']
  volumes:
  - name: 'go'
    path: '/gopath'

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
  env: ['GOPATH=/gopath']
  volumes:
  - name: 'go'
    path: '/gopath'
```

Additionally, I had to grant the App Engine Admin role to the Cloud Build service account in IAM for the `gcloud app deploy` step to succeed within Cloud Build.

Comment: This works well, thank you Jeremy, the drawback I see with this as a solution is the need to specify every non standard dependency in the  builder image arguments.

Comment: Actually a wildcard will work as well (just tested). I've updated my answer, as I agree it's simpler.

Comment: I get can not find package :C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410487/how-to-build-a-docker-image-using-cloud-build-with-sdk-in-local-machine-without