# certificate signed by unknown authority Kubernetes Engine

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

When I deploy a docker image to [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/),

[image]
 the pods can't be initialize, pods are just making a simple get request to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ 
[image: code]

I get an error message `certificate signed by unknown authority`

[image]

Comment: How do you create your container image? Do you use a Docker image which is empty (e.g. `scratch` or similar) and so won't have a root certificates bundle present?

Comment: FROM alpine
COPY backend /backend
CMD ["/backend"]
RUN chmod 755 /backend

Comment: command CMD ["/backend"] RUN chmod 755 /backend  is because I had another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488927/permission-denied-when-deploying-docker-image-to-kubernetes-engine

Comment: did you build backend Windows again?  what's the command you are using to build the binary?

Comment: yes, I would want to avoid do it in linux, now I just have one computer and in order to make the linux binary I'll need to install in my pc and I'm scared to erase all data in my computer, command to deploy: gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .

Comment: commands to build the binary:  1) set GOSS=linux 2)set GOARCH=amd64 3)go build

Comment: also I tried to build the binary with cloud build but I couldn't, I tried many combinations and any worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410487/how-to-build-a-docker-image-using-cloud-build-with-sdk-in-local-machine-without

Comment: You need `set GOOS` – this won't fix your problem, and I assume it's a typo in your comment.

Comment: Make sure you're installing the `ca-certificates` bundle in your alpine-sourced container. Add `RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*` to your `Dockerfile`, after the `RUN chmod` command (although order is mostly irrelevant).

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage my bad, actually I indeed did: "set GOOS=linux" I just typed wrong here, I'll try that solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments in your question, I expect you are running up against the common problem of Alpine base images not being populated with the `ca-certificates` package, which contains a number of root CA certificates to anchor your root of trust.

Add the following command to your `Dockerfile` to ensure these are installed in the produced image:

```
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

(we run multiple operations in a single `RUN` step to [avoid introducing unnecessary bloat](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) in the layers of your final image).

Base images which include the CA certificates package are also available in the container registry (although with this statement I make no claims as to their suitability or provenance).

Comment: thank you that completely solved it, thank you a lot :D